# SSRS: How to aggregate columns into one in a bar chart

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

A,100

B,120

C,50

D,20

Plotting this in a  Chart produces the correct result: it gives me a chart with 4 columns.

What i want however is to add all these values into one column and have the chart show only one as i will be adding more data series (via lookUp) that will show additional related data.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the dataset of the report, by summing A,B,C and D instead of selecting each one on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the chart type to a stacked column chart